# How would I go about building a widget like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image: I want a front and back picture of the body, where I can programatically color specific muscles (active or inactive during exercise for example)]

I want a front and back picture of the body, where I can programatically color specific muscles (active or inactive during exercise for example)

I didn't find any flutter-packages that really fit my need, so how would I build a widget like this on my own?
Making a picture for each muscle and layering them on top of one another with transparent backgrounds? Pre-exporting every possible version seems almost impossible, since there are almost endless possibilities.

I hope somebody on here has an idea, thanks in advance!

Comment: Using an SVG would seem the easiest - most extensive - solution, but this kind of recommendation is off-topic for the site. Try and implement a solution, then come back to us with specific problems you’re having with that implementation. Also, please take the [tour] to see what the site is for.

Comment: I think you can use `ClipPath`, `ShapeBorder` or `CustomPaint` to draw muscles. Then wrap everything inside stack, maintaining position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Flutter Shape Maker  https://fluttershapemaker.com/
Here you can design however you wish and you can get code according to your design like below code

```
child: CustomPaint(
  size: Size(WIDTH,(WIDTH*0.625).toDouble()), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
  painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
),
```

Comment: This was exactly what I ended up using. But using the "Shape Maker Web" tool for complex designs is almost impossible, so I downloaded a vector graphic editing program (Gravit Designer), designed my graphic and then used the "flutter-to-svg" converter from the link you suggested.